# How to add the date to .bash_history?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I would like to see the date on which a command is executed.

How could I do this if only the number and the command is displayed?

Before:

```
 850 cd ~
 851 nano .bashrc
 852 ls
```

After:

```
 850  2015-01-11 09:35:37: cd ~
 851  2015-01-11 09:35:43: nano .bashrc
 852  2015-01-11 09:35:49: ls
```

Do not know how to do.

Comment: Set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable.

Comment: Any reason you did't first search Google for this!?  I'm asking because the top 10 hits answers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `HISTTIMEFORMAT` in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` to:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%y-%m-%d %T"
```